# Rgbdslam installation error

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am new in ROS.
I am trying to install rgbdslam on my laptop.
I have got a following error: '/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL' and later I have got 'SiftGPU cannot be compiled. Returned: 2'.

What should I do? help me please.

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43465/rgbdslam-installation-error/) by [SHPOWER](https://answers.ros.org/users/2209/shpower/) on ROS Answers with karma: 302 on 2012-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Install all this before building the package rgbdslam,

sudo apt-get install libglew1.5-dev libdevil-dev libsuitesparse-dev libgsl0-dev.

Have you built g2o package?

I think the problem is with openGL. So, try

sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev freeglut3 mesa-common-dev libqt4-opengl binutils-gold

---

Originally posted by [Sudhan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1685/sudhan/) with karma: 171 on 2012-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1